# The pointer problem in C language, does anyone know why the output of this code is different?

Tags: c

The first code：

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int *func() {
    int n = 100;
    return &n;
}
int main() {
    int *p = func(), n;
    n = *p;
    printf("value=%d\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

output: 
value=100

The second code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int *func() {
    int n = 100;
    return &n;
}
int main() {
    int *p = func(), n;
    printf("c is an interesting language!\n");
    n = *p;
    printf("value=%d\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

output: 
c is an interesting language!
value=30

I use the debugging program and found that the printf function changed the value of n. What operation does it do inside? If anyone could give me a detailed answer, I would be grateful!

Comment: `n` is a local variable - valid only within the function. Returning and using a reference to it outside the function is Undefined Behaviour. Both code examples are not correctly formed programs.

Comment: The program has *undefined behavior* because the lifetime of a non-static, non-external variable declared within a function (or block) expires at the end of the function (or block). The code is returning a pointer to such a variable, but the variable no longer exists when it returns to the caller. Dereferencing a pointer to a non-existent variable results in *undefined behavior*. One way to think of it is that the variable `n` is "on the stack" in the stack frame of function `func`, but when `func` returns, that stack space is released and can be reused by the call to `printf` for example.

Comment: Just because first one happens to print same value you are returning **does not mean that is correct way**, It is still **not valid and undefined**.

Comment: One way to make it work: `static int n = 100;` The corresponding memory will not be freed when going outside the function

Comment: You should enable more warnings in your compiler. For GCC you can use `-Wall -Wextra`. Returning the address of a local non-static object should result in a warning.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, there is one more question. I found that the output of the second program is exactly the number of bytes in the string in printf (run under windows visual studio), for example, printf("abc") will cause the value of n to be 3. But running under macOS is a mess. Is this caused by gcc on different platforms?

Comment: The local variable 'n' inside func() is pushed into stack and similarly all local variables in main() or any functions(e.g printf) called from main() /application use the same stack. Stack variables are removed/poped (not erased) when the function is over. Now, When you use printf() the local variables (of printf  function) are actually pushed into the stack area which is removed(poped from func)... So your first example works (although not correct way of implementation), second wont because of a function call(i.e. printf) in between which replaced the value by it's local variable.

Comment: This is the nature of **undefined behavior": Anything can happen, even the appearance of [nasal demons](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).